# Need to create an API on the basis of ForeignKey in dotnet core

Tags: .net-core, core-api

Here is my Schema and with two Foreign Key in an intermediate table. I am beginner in Core dotnet so unable to crate API to show the department in the school.

```
 public class DepartmentSchool
{
    public int Id { get; set; }


    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
    public virtual Department Department{ get; set; }


    public int SchoolsId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SchoolsId")]
    public virtual Schools Schools { get; set; }
```

Here I want to get all department related to school id, how can i get all the department though the School id in dotnetcore API.

Here is the school class entity schema.

```
public partial class Schools
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UicCode { get; set; }
    public int SchoolSystemsId { get; set; }

    public string BannerUrl { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public int UserID { get; set; }    

    public int? Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public int? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public int? ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SchoolSystemsId")]
    public PrivateSchoolSystem PrivateSchoolSystems { get; set; }
```

And more here is the department schema.

```
 public partial class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public int UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public int SchoolSystemsID { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("SchoolSystemsID")]
    public virtual PrivateSchoolSystem PrivateSchoolSystems { get; set; }
```

And I am trying to get a department list in the query in the following controller.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DepartmentSchoolController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly learning_gpsContext _learning_GpsContext;
    public DepartmentSchoolController(learning_gpsContext learning_GpsContext)
    {
        _learning_GpsContext = learning_GpsContext;
    }
```

Comment: Give us more code, `School` class and `DbContext` class

Comment: Hey Vipin, if someone takes the time to help you, you should take the time to respond to the answer. Consider to accept the answer if it was helpful - if not provide some feedback why it was not helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[HttpGet("school/{schoolId}/departments")]
public IActionResult GetDepartmentsFromSchool(int schoolId)
{
    var school = _learning_GpsContext.Schools.Where(e=>e.Id == schoolId).FirstOrDefault();
    if (school == null)
        return NotFound();
    var departments = _learning_GpsContext.DepartmentSchool
        .Where(e=>e.SchoolsId == schoolId).Select(e=>e.Department);
    return Ok(departments);
}
```

For further learning check [this tutorial](https://www.forevolve.com/en/articles/2017/08/11/design-patterns-web-api-service-and-repository-part-1/). You should also understand what REST is and for basic questions always take a look at the [official documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: Ok.. Than you should accept this answer (as well as the other answers to your other questions, if they were correct). You accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side of the answer. Kind regards

Comment: What I will have to do same thing with repository pattern.

Comment: take a look at the tutorial I´ve linked in my answer. And if you have another question you should consider asking a new one.